# Return Py_RETURN_NONE or throw exception

Tags: python, c

I am writing a library that reads multiple objects from a file.
Which option is preferable(pythonic) to return if the function cannot return an object (there is no object):

1. throw exception, if yes, which type of exception?

or

2. return Py_RETURN_NONE

Comment: This is a decision that has to be made by the programmer, depending on what the function is supposed to do. If it's *always* an error (should never happen when things work normally), and the files are malformed if there are no objects, then an exception might make sense. Otherwise, it makes sense to return some value that is representative of the contents of the file, like `None` or an empty list (again, depending on the nature of the problem).

Comment: @ThomasJager Thx. It is assumed that the object may not be in the file, and this is normal.

Comment: Ok, i that case you definitely don't want to throw an exception, that should be kept for abnormal states/events. If the file acts as an array of objects and would normally always return a list, then consider an empty list (same applies for tuples and dicts). If you'd normally just return a single object (whether or not you have within it other objects) from the function, then `None` is appropriate.